# Programmatically delete subcategories and assigned posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem and can`t get that sortet. What I do is programmatically creating subcategories to a parent category and programmatically creating posts for the subcategories by processing a csv-file:

- Parent Category (empty, no posts, this should stay)
- -Sub 1
- --Sub 1-2
- ---Sub 1-3
- -Sub 2
- --Sub 2-2
- -Sub 3

This works fine.

What I want to do now is:
delete all subcategories and all the posts within these subcategories before running the script again. Just the parent category should stay and everything else should be gone.

Is this possible in a single query using $wpdb or a direct sql statement or any wordpress-function?

Thank you and kind regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds stupid,... but by asking the question I found a solution:

```
function delete_posts_title($partner) {

//delete all posts
$catposts = get_posts( array(
    'category'       => $partner['kategorie_id'],
    'numberposts'    => -1
) );
$i = 0;
foreach($catposts as $post) {
    //exclude posts that are in these categories, too
    if(!in_category( array(1,4145),$post->ID)) {
        //echo "<pre>".$post->post_title." ". $i ."</pre>";
        wp_delete_post( $post->ID, false );
        ++$i;
    }
}

//delete all subcategories
$args = array('child_of' => $partner['kategorie_id']);
$categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach($categories as $category) { 
    wp_delete_category( $category->term_id );
}
```

}